# How to escape a character in Regex expression in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I have a regex expression which removes all non alphanumeric characters. It is working fine for all special characters apart from ^. Below is the regex expression I am using.

```
String strRefernce = strReference.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}]", "").toUpperCase();
```

I tried modifying it to

```
String strRefernce = strReference.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}]\\^", "").toUpperCase();
```

and

```
String strRefernce = strReference.replaceAll("[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}^\\p{IsDigit}\\^]", "").toUpperCase();
```

But these are also not able to remove this symbol.
Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: That gives a compilation error

Comment: There is a `^` inside - remove it. Use `"[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}]"`

Comment: I have already tried it in 2 ways as mentioned above, I may not be putting it at the right position but that is what I want to know.

Comment: Do you want to remove the caret? Use `"[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}]"`

Comment: I want to remove all special characters including caret.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `^` inside `[^...]` is a negation mark making the character class a negated one (matching characters other than what is inside).

The second one inside is considered a literal - thus, it should not be matched with the regex. Remove it, and a caret will get matched with it:

```
"[^\\p{IsAlphabetic}\\p{IsDigit}]"
```

or even shorter:

```
"(?U)\\P{Alnum}"
```

The `\P{Alnum}` class stands for any character other than *an alphanumeric character: `[\p{Alpha}\p{Digit}]`* (see [Java regex reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). When you pass `(?U)`, the `\P{Alnum}` class will not match Unicode letters. See [this IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/q6Lj74).

Add a `+` at the end if you want to remove whole chunks of symbols other than `\\p{IsAlphabetic}` and `\\p{IsDigit}`.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is from the [OCPSoft Web site](http://www.ocpsoft.org/tutorials/regular-expressions/java-visual-regex-tester/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Adding + symbol removes a group of special characters in one go instead of going one by one. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes. Just use `.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}+", "")` - with the `+` after either your character class or as I suggest the shorthand character class.

Comment: If I am not wrong using Alnum will also remove unicode charaters like latin, greek which I don't want. That is the reason I have used IsAlphabetic and IsDigit

Comment: You can use `"(?U)\\P{Alnum}+"` then. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/q6Lj74). The `(?U)` will make the pattern Unicode-aware. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works as well.

```
System.out.println("Text 尖酸[刻薄 ^, More _0As text °ÑÑ"".replaceAll("(?U)[^[\\W_]]+", " "));
```

Output

```
Text 尖酸 刻薄 More 0As text Ñ Ñ
```

Not sure but the word might be the more comprehensive list of alphanum characters.

`[\\W_]` is a class containing non-words and an underscore.

When put into a negative Java class construct it becomes

`[^[\\W_]]` is a negative class of a union between nothing and
a class containing non-words and an underscore.